# Dynamically created canvas not recognized/manipulatable

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to create and fill a canvas as blue without using any html. I have been successful in rendering an empty canvas. The issue occurs when I try to fill the canvas with a color as seen below in the second code snippet. In the two snippets below, the only difference is which canvas is filled with blue (`document.getElementsByClassName("blueCanvas")[0]` in the first one, which works, and `document.getElementsByClassName("blueCanvas")[2]`, which should fill the dynamically created canvas, and fails.

some things I have tried/noticed:

First I thought it was an issue with the order in the execution in the creation of the canvas and the js that tries to fill it, but the problem persists even when I create the canvas in the beginning of the `<body>`. I also thought it might be an issue of append the element to the DOM but it renders an empty canvas so I don't see how that's possible.

Thanks.

```js
var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
newCanvas.width = '300';
newCanvas.height = '150'
newCanvas.className = 'blueCanvas';
newCanvas.style = 'border:1px solid black'
newCanvas.innerHTML = '<canvas> </canvas>';
document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("blueCanvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class='blueCanvas' width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas" class='blueCanvas' width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

```js
var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        newCanvas.width = '300';
        newCanvas.height = '150'
        newCanvas.className='blueCanvas';
        newCanvas.style= 'border:1px solid black'
        newCanvas.innerHTML = '<canvas> </canvas>';
document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("blueCanvas")[2];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class='blueCanvas' width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas" class='blueCanvas' width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: Why did you put another canvas within a canvas? `newCanvas.class` is incorrect. HTML class attribute in JavaScript is`newCanvas.className`.

Comment: I am sorry but where did I put another canvas within the canvas? I changed  `newCanvas.class` thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `newCanvas.innerHTML = '<canvas> </canvas>';`. `newCanvas` is already a canvas Element. Note that you don't need to get the Element with `document.getElementsByClassName("blueCanvas")[2];`. `newCanvas` is your canvas Element. So, `const ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');`.

Comment: oh. Well it looks like `newCanvas.className` fixed it. I would  mark your answer correct if you make it as an answer instead of a comment (which I don't think is possible to mark correct). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I know you read my comments:

```
function blueCanvas(){
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas'), style = canvas.style, ctx;
  canvas.width = 300; canvas.height = 150; canvas.className = 'blueCanvas';
  style.border = '1px solid black'; ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
}
blueCanvas();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you want.

Maybe this will help

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 400;  // size it
canvas.height = 300;
canvas.className = 'blueCanvas'; // assign class name
document.body.appendChild(canvas); // add to document

// get context
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// fill it with blue
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.font = "32px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Dynamically added canvas", 200, 100);
```

Comment: It seems the only problem with my code was writing `canvas.class` instead of `canvas.className' (as pointed out in the comments). The code is now working properly.